# Learning contextual data using a variational quantum circuit

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-computer, non-locality, data

This question is about contextuality in quantum mechanics, about non-quantum data also showing contextuality.

**Definition for the specifics of the question as well as an example of contextuality in quantum mechanics**

I have a set of measurements acting on a 2 qubit state for whom the statistics of the measurement result is contextual.

By that I mean the following. My 4 measurements $A,C,a,c$ with possible value $+,-$ have the following commutation relation. $[A,C]=0$,  $[A,a]=0$, $[a,c]=0$, $[C,c]=0$. You could put them in a table and say that observables in the same row or in the same column commute.
\begin{equation}
\begin{bmatrix}
    A & C \\
    a & c 
\end{bmatrix}
\end{equation}
Define the context of $A$ as the other commuting observables I observe at the same time. (could be $Aa$, or $AC$)

Looking at the following expectation value,
\begin{equation}
    <E>=<AC>+<Aa>+<ac>-<Cc>
\end{equation}
Trying to assume pre-existing measurement results for $A,C,a,c$ **noncontextualy** (without taking the measurement context into account), then we see that $<E>_{NC}\leq 2$. (To see it, set all values A=C=a=c=1, see that this implies =2 and try to change them to make the expectation larger, not change can be made that makes it larger than 2)

With notation $Z_1=\sigma_z\otimes\mathcal{I}$, we choose $A=Z_1$, $C=Z_1Z_2$, $a=Z_1X_2$, and $c=Y_1Y_2$.

For $|MM>=\cos(\frac{\pi}{8})^2|00>+\sin(\frac{\pi}{8})|11>+\cos(\frac{\pi}{8})\sin(\frac{\pi}{8})(|01>+|10>)$, we see that $<E>_{QM}=1+\sqrt{2}><E_{NC}>$.

The inequality is violated and thus the noncontextuality assumption is false, quantum mechanics is contextual.

This is a case of state-dependent contextuality. The reason QM can violate this inequality is that probablity for assignment of values to the observables is context-dependant, even when that context is other commuting observables.
What this means from a statistics standpoint is that $P(A,C),P(A,a),P(a,c),P(C,c)$ do not derive from a global distribution $P(A,C,a,c)$ assigning probabilities to the various results ++++, +++-, ++-+, .... It does not derive from it in the sense that there is no $P(A,C,a,c)$ such that the distributions over contexts such as $P(A,C)$ are not marginales. ($P(A,C)\neq\sum_{a,c}P(A,C,a,c)$)

It may remind you of non-locality and that is because contextuality is a generalization of non-locality.

**The question**

By the commutation relations, I can consider pairs of commuting measurements on the same state, ie $AC\ket{\psi}$, and since the order doesn't matter, I can look at the statistics of the measurement results for this pair $(A,C)=\{++, +-, -+, --\}$, and similarly for the other pairs $(A,a)$, $(a,c)$, $(C,c)$.

Imagining I can generates $|MM>$, measure 2 randomly chosen (from A,C,a,c) commuting observables, reset the state and do it enought, I would get the following statistics.

[image: Distributions over ++, +-, -+, -- for the 4 contexts]

What is a set of classical data that has similar properties? It doesn't have to be the same distributions, just that it corresponds to 4 "questions" that I can ask in the same pairs as the contexts defined above, and that the statistics of the answers to the "questions" also be contextual, ie does not derive from a global distribution.

I would like to find a dataset for whom a VQC would learn the |MM> state when trying to learn the data.

I dont have much experience posting, so let me know if there are things that need clarification